# Geometry functions in where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Objects` in MySQL:

`id int(11),
objekt_x decimal(9,15),
objekt_y decimal(9,15)`

Where objekt_x and objekt_y are objects longitude and latitude.
In my application I create a bounding polygon with google maps, so I get polygon coordinates.

Now i have to select objects from SQL table which are inside selected polygon.

`SELECT * FROM Objects`

`WHERE Intersects(`

`GeomFromText("POINT(object_x object_x)"),`

`GeomFromText("POLYGON((52.82058030980633 20.01708984375,52.734185230629436 22.115478515625,52.82058030980633 20.01708984375))")`

`) = 1`

My problem is how to build a 'POINT' fragment of my code, so it would work my SQL table.
Any help appreciate :)

Comment: I've solved that. The solution is:

`SELECT * FROM Objekts where `

`MBRContains(`

`GeomFromText("POLYGON((52.82058030980633 20.01708984375,51.49289882464652 19.896240234375,52.82058030980633 20.01708984375))"),`

`GeomFromText(CONCAT("POINT(",obiekt_x," ",obiekt_y,")"))`

`) = 1`

Probably it will work also with Intersects function. The clue is to use a function to concatenate string with column names while creating a POINT object.